# htaccess - Remove sub dir from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to remove subdir from this url

```
www.example.com/subdir/dir/page
```

but only when the url has the structure subdir/dir in it.
So when the url is

```
www.example.com/subdir/page
```

nothing happens.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? You want to redirect the browser so that the "dir" doesn't show up in the location bar? You want to be able to generate links without the "dir" but internally rewrite them back? What is "subdir" and "dir"? Are they arbitrarily anything or specifically "subdir" and "dir" literally?

Comment: At the moment Google has listed these url structures in the search results and I want to 301 redirect them to the right page, which is the url structure without the subdir/ part

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subdir/dir/(.*) http://www.example.com/dir/$1
```